# Check a status and alert me by email if it returns false

Tags: raspberry-pi, cryptocurrency

So I finished setting up my Raspberry Pi 3 for a crypto wallet, which need to be 24/7 running for staking (it means that if you have money on the wallet and let it run, sometimes you'll get a reward for that)

But now I want to automatize things for a bit, so here is the situation :
I want to create a script running 24/7 and alerting me by email if staking is off, or if the wallet crash, to check that I have a command, `getinfo` which returns :

￼

```
{
    "version" : 3000600,
    "protocolversion" : 70912,
    "walletversion" : 61000,
    "balance" : 0.00000000,
    "zerocoinbalance" : 0.00000000,
    "blocks" : 1054716,
    "timeoffset" : 0,
    "connections" : 16,
    "proxy" : "",
    "difficulty" : 194154.74931052,
    "testnet" : false,
    "moneysupply" : 55667642.94565828,
    "zPIVsupply" : {
        "1" : 13973.00000000,
        "5" : 14615.00000000,
        "10" : 63670.00000000,
        "50" : 66800.00000000,
        "100" : 200800.00000000,
        "500" : 193000.00000000,
        "1000" : 350000.00000000,
        "5000" : 380000.00000000,
        "total" : 1282858.00000000
    },
    "keypoololdest" : 1498147446,
    "keypoolsize" : 1001,
    "unlocked_until" : 0,
    "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
    "relayfee" : 0.00010000,
    "staking status" : "Staking Not Active", # here is the line that interest me
    "errors" : ""
}
```

and also the command `getstakingstatus` which returns :

```
{
    "validtime" : true,
    "haveconnections" : true,
    "walletunlocked" : false,
    "mintablecoins" : false,
    "enoughcoins" : true,
    "mnsync" : true,
    "staking status" : false
}
```

As you can see, there is a line "staking status", and I want to check if it's returning "true" or "Staking Active"
I also want to be able to restart the wallet in case it crashes, so I don't ave to go to my rpi and restart it by hand..

So my bash knowledge is very limited, in school I only had two lessons of Bash and this was my weakest language.. I have some ideas on how to do that, but I'm not quite sure so I planned on doing something like that :

```
./pivx-cli getinfo > info.txt
cat info.txt | grep -E 'staking status'
```

and that's basically all I can do :| 
Though I know that the grep command will only return me "staking status", I don't know how to get the whole line.. 
I know that for a condition I need to use something like 
if
...
fi ?
And for the email I guess I have to set up a mail server, and have a file where every information I want mentioned

Sorry if it's messy but I have really no idea on how to do that, I'm trying my best but I have close to no knowledge in that language !

If you need anything else just tell me and I'll do my best to provide you the information, even though I'd rather learn by myself so maybe a few links could be enough !

Thank you

Comment: You could post this in the RPi stack exchange site. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AlanPallath the question is about programming. This is the correct place

Comment: Yeah but he's right I think I will post there too just in case someone can help me there